# Check value to 'ceiling' values and return corresponding variable

Tags: java, if-statement, implementation

I have some constants f.e.:

```
BigDecimal ceiling1 = new BigDecimal(5);
BigDecimal ceiling2 = new BigDecimal(10);
BigDecimal ceiling3 = new BigDecimal(20);

BigDecimal rate1 = new BigDecimal(0.01);
BigDecimal rate2 = new BigDecimal(0.02);
BigDecimal rate3 = new BigDecimal(0.04);
BigDecimal rate4 = new BigDecimal(0.09);
```

Now based on a parameter f.e.:

```
BigDecimal arg = new BigDecimal(6);
```

I want to retrieve the right rate which is based on this if structure (simplified):

```
if(arg <= ceiling1) {
   rate = rate1;
}else if(arg <= ceiling2) {
   rate = rate2;
} else if (arg <= ceiling3) {
   rate = rate3;
}else rate = rate4;
```

So in my example `rate` should be `rate2`

But I'm wondering if someone knows a better way to implement this, instead of a bunch of ifs.

Any pointers are welcome!

**PS: I know my code isn't 100% right, just wanted to show the idea**

Comment: Are you aware that BigDecimals don't compare like that? Why are you using BigDecimal anyway?

Comment: Are there always exactly three ceilings and four rates or can this vary? How many will there be in your real code?

Comment: @DJClayworth yes i know that's why i put "(simplified)". Sorry for the confusion, I just wanted to show the idea behind it.

Comment: @A.H. this can vary, but will not be many (1-10)

Comment: First you should think of algorithm so your Ceilings would be increment dynamically. Second override Ceiling hashCode() method based on your algorithm outcome. Third define a HashMap of ratings, where Key is your Ceiling hashCode() result constant and Value as a Rating (eg. Enum). Thats it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store your ceilings as keys in a TreeMap and your rates as values. Then use floorEntry and see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376498/is-there-a-nearest-key-map-datastructure).

```
final TreeMap<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> rates = new TreeMap<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>();
rates.put(new BigDecimal(0), new BigDecimal(0.01));
rates.put(new BigDecimal(5), new BigDecimal(0.02));
rates.put(new BigDecimal(10), new BigDecimal(0.04));
rates.put(new BigDecimal(20), new BigDecimal(0.09));

System.out.println(rates.floorEntry(new BigDecimal(0)).getValue());
System.out.println(rates.floorEntry(new BigDecimal(6)).getValue());
System.out.println(rates.floorEntry(new BigDecimal(10)).getValue());
System.out.println(rates.floorEntry(new BigDecimal(100)).getValue());
```

Test: http://ideone.com/VrucK. You may want to use a different representation as you can see in the test it looks ugly(Like Integers for the ceiling). Btw the ugly output comes from the fact that 0.01 is a double [which does funny things with decimal representations](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_need_for_bigdecimal).

Edit: Suggested [cleanup](http://ideone.com/CeS2H).

Comment: A TreeMap is a very heavyweight object for storing a handful of values. A couple of arrays will do the job much easier.

Comment: How is that heavyweight especially considering its less code and obvious what its doing.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably get rid of the BigDecimal objects and store the rates (and the ceilings) as CONSTANTS (FINAL variables).
Then i will use a Switch statement to find the right rate.

Answer (score 1):

```
class RateCalculator {
  double ceiling[] = new double[]{5,10,20};
  double rate[] = new double[]{0.01,0.02,0.04}
  // use assertions to ensure that the sizes of these two arrays are equal.
  // ensure that successive values in ceiling are higher than the last.
  public double calculateRate(double value) {
    for (int i=0;i<ceiling.length;++i) {
      if (value < ceiling[i]) {
        return rate[i];
      }
    // the rate for values higher than the highest ceiling
    return 0.09;
  }
}
```

You can change the number of rates by changing the size of the arrays. Some of the values should be named constants to follow good programming style - they are left as numbers here to illustrate the correspondance between the OPs values and the ones here.

Conversion to BigDecimal is left as an exercise for the reader.